# group by hour using time alone (ex:10:00:00 AM) in spark sql in java?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I want to group my records in an hour as well as 15 minutes basis.

So 
My Dataset is,

```
    |Date   |Time       | speed |avg|
    |1/1/2016|10:00:00 AM|     21| 10|
    |1/1/2016|10:00:00 PM|     45| 10|
    |1/1/2016|11:15:00 AM|     35| 10|
    |1/1/2016|12:15:00 PM|     25| 20|
    |1/1/2016|01:30:00 AM|     15| 30|
```

From the above dataset I want to group the avg speed and count of avg:
sample query i have tried in spark sql is :

```
spark.sql(select Time, avg(speed),count(avg) from dataset group by Time)
```

Comment: why do you have AM/PM in your data? It is already in 24h format.

Comment: @philantrovert ..Hi buddy I changed it to 12h format?.. it was a typo

Comment: you mean group by hour of the day regardless of minutes?

Comment: yes it should be regardless of day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new column with the data you want to gorup on :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
df = df.withColumn("hour", functions.concat(
                functions.split(df.col("Time"), " ").getItem(1), 
                functions.lit(":"), 
                functions.split(df.col("Time"), ":").getItem(0)
            ));
df.show();

+--------+-----------+-----+---+-----+
|    Date|       Time|speed|avg| hour|
+--------+-----------+-----+---+-----+
|1/1/2016|10:00:00 AM|   21| 10|10:AM|
|1/1/2016|10:00:00 PM|   45| 10|10:PM|
|1/1/2016|11:15:00 AM|   35| 10|11:AM|
|1/1/2016|12:15:00 PM|   25| 20|12:PM|
|1/1/2016|01:30:00 AM|   15| 30|01:AM|
+--------+-----------+-----+---+-----+
```

Then you can aggreagate on this new column :

```
df = df.groupBy("hour")
       .agg(functions.avg("speed"), functions.count("avg"));
df.show();

+-----+----------+----------+
| hour|avg(speed)|count(avg)|
+-----+----------+----------+
|10:AM|      21.0|         1|
|12:PM|      25.0|         1|
|11:AM|      35.0|         1|
|10:PM|      45.0|         1|
|01:AM|      15.0|         1|
+-----+----------+----------+
```

You can add the Date in the groupby if you need to goup by dates too :

```
df.groupBy("hour", "Date")
    .agg(functions.avg("speed"), functions.count("avg"))
    .show()

+-----+--------+----------+----------+
| hour|    Date|avg(speed)|count(avg)|
+-----+--------+----------+----------+
|01:AM|1/1/2016|      15.0|         1|
|10:AM|1/1/2016|      21.0|         1|
|10:PM|1/1/2016|      45.0|         1|
|12:PM|1/1/2016|      25.0|         1|
|11:AM|1/1/2016|      35.0|         1|
+-----+--------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Its worked and do you know how to do the same for 15 minutes ?

Answer (score 1):

Extract hour from time and use it in group by

```
SELECT Extract(HOUR From TIME) AS time1, Avg(speed),Count(Avg) FROM DATASET GROUP BY time1
```

Comment: Exception encountered: 
mismatched input 'From' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 20)

== SQL ==
SELECT Extract(HOUR From Time)

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array(
("1/1/2016","10:00:00 AM","21","10"),
("1/1/2016","10:00:00 PM","45","10"),
("1/1/2016","11:15:00 AM","35","10"),
("1/1/2016","12:15:00 PM","25","20"),
("1/1/2016","01:30:00 AM","15","30"))).toDF("date", "time", "speed", "avg")

df.registerTempTable("dataset")
```

You need to convert the string to date/time type and then extract the hour in the group by clause

```
sqlContext.sql("""
     SELECT hour(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat_ws(" ", date, time), "dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss aa") ) ) as hours, 
     avg(speed) as avg_speed, count(avg) as cnt_avg 
     from dataset 
     group by hour(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat_ws(" ", date, time), "dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss aa") ) )
 """).show

+-----+---------+-------+
|hours|avg_speed|cnt_avg|
+-----+---------+-------+
|    1|     15.0|      1|
|   10|     21.0|      1|
|   11|     35.0|      1|
|   12|     25.0|      1|
|   22|     45.0|      1|
+-----+---------+-------+
```